# Enterprise edition of our iPad app not downloading

Tags: ios, objective-c, ad-hoc-distribution, enterprise-distribution

We have created an enterprise edition of our iPad app. and we were using it since last 15 days. but url suddenly stopped working. we are not able to install application now.

Please help me out guys.

Comment: can you give more details about your problem. What you use to provide your app? What is the error?

Comment: Error: "There is no application set to open the URL itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=index.php%3Fplist%3DMyApp".......but earlier it was working fine, i din't change anything to my side.

Comment: didi you check if you have a "IPA" file created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone revoked the distribution profile used to sign the app, the installation will no longer work.